# How to make buttons with custom shapes?

Tags: ios, button

I'm developing an iPhone app that requires buttons to be of shapes other than rectangles/squares for eg, an amoeba shaped button. Also, when the button is clicked, the button is highlighted only as much as its size. So just setting a background image only is not enough. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to make pre-rendered images for both the normal state and selected state.  Then set use `setBackgroundImage: forState:` to set each image to it's appropriate state.

I should add, your pre-rendered images would include transparency around the "amoeba" shape and would therefore give the illusion of an "amoeba" shaped button. Combining that with a selected state image of the selected state of the "amoeba" shape as well as disabling highlightAdjustsImage should give you the result you desire. Or am I still misunderstanding something?

Comment: This _is_ how you want to do it, but actually with `-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state`  They can be set in IB (my preference).  There are 4 possible states of the button: normal, highlighted, selected, and disabled.  It sounds like you minimally want normal and highlighted.