# How to set the back button shape as back arrow for normal view?

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application in which I do not use the navigation controller. But I am using the navigation bar for every page. In that I want to place a back button that looks the same as UINavigation controller's back button. I have written the below code for that. But it does n't give the output that I want. So please tell me how to do that.

```
UINavigationItem *odritm=[[UINavigationItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Ins"];

UIButton* backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:101];

 [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backAction)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[backButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
 UIBarButtonItem* backItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];

odritm.leftBarButtonItem=backItem;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a custom button and set its background image as a snapshot of the arrow-shaped back button. To counter the problem of showing a highlighted non-rectangular button, refer [How to make buttons with custom shapes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571294/how-to-make-buttons-with-custom-shapes).

Also, I don't think there's a 'buttonWithType:101' ... the maximum value possible is 5

EDIT: you'll have to use transparent images.